# How to write junit test case using mockito when we have rowmapper?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

How to write junit test case for this code using mockito?

```
List<Employee> employee = jdbctemplate.query("select * from employee", new RowMapper<Employee>(){  
@Override  
public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {  
  Employee e = new Employee();  
  e.setId(rs.getString("ID"));         
  e.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));    
  return e;  
}  
});
```

Comment: What is "this code"? Is it just the row mapper, or is it the whole JDBC query with the SQL statement?

Comment: Then you're better off with an _integration test_ which uses a real database or a lightweight in-memory database (e.g. hsql).

Comment: In case if it is just row mapper then how to write junit test case for this?

Comment: I've posted one possibility as an answer. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

A unit test for the row mapper would be built in the following manner:

- Mock the JDBC result set,
- Mock "get" methods of the result set to return specific values for relevant columns,
- Invoke the row mapper,
- Test the values of the result entity.

The code could be similar to the following:

```
// Having:
final var resultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);
when(resultSet.getString("ID")).thenReturn("4711");
when(resultSet.getString("Name")).thenReturn("John Doe");

// When:
final var employee = myRowMapper.mapRow(resultSet, 12345);

// Then:
assertEquals("4711", employee.getId());
assertEquals("John Doe", employee.getName());
```

Comment: Is this the only way or we can use any other approach?

Comment: There are almost always many ways to solve the same problem :) What exact requirements do you have?

Comment: What is "myRowMapper" in above code?

Comment: It's the row mapper being tested. If you only test the row mapper, then you need to extract it into a separate class of a helper function.

Comment: JdbcTemplate jt = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
    " How to add values to this list "
    Mockito.when(jt.query(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn(list);

Comment: If i use above code how to add values to list of object(employee) and what changes do I need to make for this code to work?